# Unknown option: -bitcode_verify

Tags: watchkit, xcode7

So, I managed to get my iOS App and WatchKit app running fine but when I (first clean) run Archive, the compiler throws the following error:

> ld: unknown option: -bitcode_verify
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It relates to the WatchKit Extension but I'm completely blank on where to start.

(Xcode 7.0.1 / Deployment target iOS 8.2 / WatchOS 2.0)

Thanks again!
/Frederik

Answer (score 0):

When I realized the only thing left to do was to create a brand new project and start copy pasting, I created a new iOS project and added a WatchKit target. Without adding any code I tried to build and archive the project and I got the same compiler error which led me to the conclusion that the problem laid with Xcode itself. After a complete uninstall (all associated files removed) and then a new install, voila! It compiles normally.